# Jquery Replace Characters from input value

Tags: jquery

I have a script I pieced together to grab the value of an input field, do some calculations, and return a value.

Somewhere in that code I need to take the value of the input field and remove any dollar signs, commas, and periods.

I assume I need to add   .replace(/\$.,/g, '')   somewhere but every way I've tried causes the calculations not to work.

Any help?

```
<form action="" method="" id="savings_form">

        <input type="text" name="input_amount" id="input_amount" />

       <div id="msg" style="display:none;"></div>

       <p id="site_commission_box" style="display: none;">Total savings: <b>$<span class="text_decoration"></span></b></p>

</form>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
// cache elements that are used at least twice
var $amount = $("#input_amount"),
    $msg = $("#msg"),
    $commission = $("#site_commission_box");

// attach handler to input keydown event
$amount.keyup(function(e){

    var amount = parseFloat($amount.val().replace(/\//g, '-'));

    //check for minimum commission ... if home is less than $200,000.00, use the following calculation
    if (amount < 200000) {
        commission = amount*0.03 - 3300;
    }else{
        commission = amount*0.03 - amount*0.0165;
    }

    if (isNaN(commission) || isNaN(amount)) {
        $msg.hide();
        $commission.hide();
        return;
    }

    $msg.hide();
    $commission
        .fadeIn()
        .find("span")
            .text((commission).toFixed(2));
});

});
<script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7hj98br0/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is this:

```
var amount = parseFloat($amount.val().replace(/(\$|,)/g, ''));
```

Notice that I removed the `.` from your Regular Expression, and also edited it a bit.

You can find a working [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/7hj98br0/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `\D` to replace all non-digit characters from the string before you parse it to float. Also in case of empty string if there are no numbers at all it makes sense to provide fallback like `0` so that `parseFloat` doesn't return NaN:

```
var amount = parseFloat($amount.val().replace(/\D/g, '') || 0);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7hj98br0/4/

Comment: Although this might not affect the OP, but if you replace periods, it will change the meaning of decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/7hj98br0/3/

```
var amountVal = $amount.val().replace(/\D/g,'');
var amount = parseFloat(amountVal);
```

gets rid of all non numeric values during your calculation